# Strange PHP Reaction

Tags: php, oop, variables, scope, visibility

I'm getting some wierd reactions when running this script.

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    class A {
        protected $varOne = array(
            "subVar1" => "",
            "subVar2" => "",
            "subVar3" => "",
            "subVar4" => "",
        );

        public function init() {
            $b = new B();
            $b->funTest();
            echo( "One Two Three" );
            echo( "<br />" );
            print_r( $this->varOne );
            echo( "<br />" );
        }

        protected function setValue( $key, $value ) {
            $this->varOne[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    class B extends A {
        public function funTest() {
            $this->setValue( "subVar1", "21" );
            $this->setValue( "subVar2", "22" );
            $this->setValue( "subVar3", "23" );
            $this->setValue( "subVar4", "24" );
            echo( "Four Five Six" );
            echo( "<br />" );
            print_r( $this->varOne );
            echo( "<br />" );
        }
    }

    $a = new A();
    $a->init();
```

Now the output here troubles me.

```
OUTPUT:
Four Five Six // As Expected
Array ( [subVar1] => 21 [subVar2] => 22 [subVar3] => 23 [subVar4] => 24 ) // As Expected
One Two Three // As Expected
Array ( [subVar1] => [subVar2] => [subVar3] => [subVar4] => ) // Wait, WTF?
```

Why are the variables empty when called from class A?

Also when setting the visibility to private, the variable is NULL/EMPTY when called from class B.

**EDIT:**

This seams to give me my needed result, Thanks to all for the help.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

class A {
    protected $varOne = array(
        "subVar1" => "",
        "subVar2" => "",
        "subVar3" => "",
        "subVar4" => "",
    );

    public function init() {
        echo( "One Two Three" );
        echo( "<br />" );
        print_r( $this->varOne );
        echo( "<br />" );
        $b = new B();
        $this->varOne = $b->funTest();
        echo( "One Two Three" );
        echo( "<br />" );
        print_r( $this->varOne );
        echo( "<br />" );
    }

    protected function setValue( $key, $value ) {
        $this->varOne[$key] = $value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function funTest() {
        $this->setValue( "subVar1", "21" );
        $this->setValue( "subVar2", "22" );
        $this->setValue( "subVar3", "23" );
        $this->setValue( "subVar4", "24" );
        return( $this->varOne );
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->init();
```

Comment: You defined `fun_test` in the subclass of `A`. `A` can't inherit the method from its subclass `B`.

Comment: @Mike, Class A does not need to inherit the method funTest from class B  though.

Comment: It's not that it needs to 'inherit' the method but rather class `A` has no definition for `fun_test`. Class `B` has knowledge and access to all fields and methods from class `A` but class `A`  has no access to methods or fields from class `B`. When you call `fun_test` in `B` you are only effecting the values of `B`. `A`'s values remain `NULL`.

Comment: So from my code, what is the method "setValue" doing?

Comment: You make all your `setValue` calls in `B` but none of them in `A`. What it's doing is setting the values of the `$varOne` array *for its instance only*, that means only `B` is effected. `A` has an instance of `$varOne` as well but because the instance of `A` never called `funTest` in its instance, those values were never updated and thus remain `NULL`.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that makes sense. Is there a way that I can make the setValue method set the values in class A rather than B?

Comment: Copy paste it into `A`. `B` will still have access ;)

Comment: Move funTest to A? setValue is already in A.

Comment: Yes but you need to call it in A

Comment: Unfortunately I do need seaperate classes though. :(

Comment: I'm assuming this is a school project? If you move the definition to A you can remove the definition from B, *but* you'll still be able to call it from B

Comment: Nah, proprietary system. The only real requirement is I need class B to set the variables in class A through a function/method in class A. Ultimately, $varOne will be private and class A will be doing verification via the setValue method. Class A will not have access to the variables that class B passes to setValue to set in class A.

Comment: Class A will then do more unrelated work.

Answer (score 0):

As the comments point out: with the `new` keyword you create a new instance of B and anything referring `$this` will only update values inside the B instance and values inside A remain unchanged.

To update A from within B without copy-pasting the method you could do something like below. I adapted the code with a `$target` parameter so you could pass along `$this` with `funTest`

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

class A {
    protected $varOne = array(
        "subVar1" => "",
        "subVar2" => "",
        "subVar3" => "",
        "subVar4" => "",
    );

    public function init() {
        $b = new B();
        $b->funTest($this);
        echo( "One Two Three" );
        echo( "<br />" );
        print_r( $this->varOne );
        echo( "<br />" );
    }

    protected function setValue( $key, $value ) {
        $this->varOne[$key] = $value;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public function funTest($target) {
        $target->setValue( "subVar1", "21" );
        $target->setValue( "subVar2", "22" );
        $target->setValue( "subVar3", "23" );
        $target->setValue( "subVar4", "24" );
        echo( "Four Five Six" );
        echo( "<br />" );
        print_r( $target->varOne );
        echo( "<br />" );
    }
}

$a = new A();
$a->init();
```

This gives your expected behaviour:

```
Four Five Six
Array ( [subVar1] => 21 [subVar2] => 22 [subVar3] => 23 [subVar4] => 24 ) 
One Two Three
Array ( [subVar1] => 21 [subVar2] => 22 [subVar3] => 23 [subVar4] => 24 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, definitly closer to what im looking for except I am trying to make class B just get the data for class A to "do work" on.

Comment: I missed the part where you added $target->. Much closer to what i'm looking for.

Comment: The trouble is that A nor B can have any data before you create an instance (`new`) of it. And if you create two instances ($a and $b) there will be two places where the data lives.

Comment: I was just about to go this route, then I decided to go with what I updated the OP with. Thanks again for the help, will use this in the future for sure though.